# Maven - Validate integrity of dependencies and plugins

Tags: maven

Is there a way using Maven (or a plugin) to provide integrity information about used dependencies and plugins (hash and file sizes) to verify that the downloaded artifacts are legit and have not been tampered with?

It appears there exists a plugin for Gradle, but I have not tested it: https://github.com/vlsi/vlsi-release-plugins/tree/master/plugins/checksum-dependency-plugin

The reason why I am asking is because sometimes you use repositories other than *central* and that repository might provide malicious artifacts. A case where this happened is described [here](https://blog.autsoft.hu/a-confusing-dependency/).

Edit: To clarify:

- Setting up an own repository is not an option because this is not a corporate environment, but an open source project.
- These repositories other than *central* have to be used because the artifacts in question are not uploaded to *central*. And only installing the artifacts to the local repository would make it more difficult for others to use the project.

Comment: The first and most important step is to use https (which is the only way since [January 2020](https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https) and also activate the checksum policy https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/ Apart from that the documentation on the mentioned link seemed to be incorrect.

Comment: @khmarbaise while your suggestions are good they do not solve the specific issue I am describing. In my case the repository could (as described in the blog post) contain malicious artifacts. Neither using https nor verifying the repository provided checksums would help because they are controlled by the malicious actor. Also which documentation in which link is incorrect?

Comment: The first thing is if you decide to use a different repository you should check if this is really needed. Furthermore you should run an internal repository in your corporate environment and check (review) the things you add. To be honest I prevent using bintray cause those can be changed by the maintainers of the packages which is exactly what I like to prevent (in contradiction to central; immutable). And yes this will not help with the situation as described related to bintray. And furthermore you have to check all the dependencies you are using.

Comment: And of course this takes time (security always takes times). No alternative. Strong recommendation is using a repository manager internally; review everything you use;  get a copy into your own repository manager; That helps a lot...

Comment: The last chapter of the blog [post](https://blog.autsoft.hu/a-confusing-dependency/) `Of course you could run your own internal Maven repository for your company and have every project rely on that exclusively, with only carefully reviewed and verified packages being imported there. Most won't have time to be so careful about dependencies.`. This shows the ignorance about security. We don't have time

Comment: @khmarbaise, I have updated the question to describe that setting up an own repository is not an option. But thanks for the comments you made about security anyways.

Comment: The question from my side would be: Why are those other artifacts not uploaded to central? Central requires some foundational requirements for artifacts to uploaded to central. Of course there is no 100% safety?  There exists pluglins/extensions which could help a little bit here but from where do you get those things? And do you trust those sources? By asking integrity you are in the end talking about trust? I personally do not rely on artifacts which are not coming from central if I need to I will get the repos and build them on my own...